# print using plsql dynamic content region

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have a page consist of two regions .the first is ststic content with 3 page item one of them is LOV and the others are dates.
the second region is type of plsql dynamic content that should to print the data based on the first region
this is the code i have used in my plsql dynamic content.
when i press on the button print to print region ,I get a javascript error
i have attatched the photo of my error.

```
V_CUSTOMER_ID number;
V_apartment_id number;
counter NUMBER := 1; -- Counter variable for sequence number
V_CUST_NAME varchar(300);
v_fdate date;
V_tDate date;
v_date date;   
V_AMOUNT number;
V_pay_method varchar(300);
V_pay_date date;     
V_DESC varchar(300);



CURSOR invoice_details IS
   select cust_id,cust_name,AMOUNT,PAYMENT_METHOD,PAYMENT_DATE,APARTMENT_ID,APARTMENT_DESC
from CUSTOMERS,PAYMENTS
where CUSTOMERS.cust_id=PAYMENTS.CUSTOMER_ID
and APARTMENT_ID=:P62_APARTMENT_ID
and payment_date between :P62_FROM_DATE and :P62_TO_DATE
order by payment_date;
BEGIN


    htp.p('<a type="button1" class="button button1 fa fa-print" id="print" type="button" onclick="printdiv(''div_print1'');" value="Print"><b class=''fa fa-print''>طباعة</b></a>' ||
         '<div id=''div_print1'' style=''margin-top:5px;''> ');
    htp.p('<div style="float:left; margin-left:20px;">');
    SELECT 
            cust_id,
            CUST_NAME,
            AMOUNT,
            PAYMENT_METHOD,
            PAYMENT_DATE,
            PAYMENT_DATE,
            APARTMENT_ID,
            APARTMENT_DESC
        INTO 
            V_CUSTOMER_ID,
            V_CUST_NAME,
            V_AMOUNT,
            V_pay_method,
            V_pay_date,
            v_date,
            V_apartment_id,
            V_DESC
        
        FROM 
            CUSTOMERS,PAYMENTS
        
        where CUSTOMERS.cust_id=PAYMENTS.CUSTOMER_ID
        and APARTMENT_ID=:P62_APARTMENT_ID
        and payment_date between :P62_FROM_DATE and :P62_TO_DATE;
       
        v_fdate :=:P62_FROM_DATE; 
        V_tDate :=:P62_TO_DATE;
            
    htp.p('<style>');
    htp.p('table {');
    htp.p('    border-collapse: collapse;');
    htp.p('    width: 100%;');
    htp.p('}');
    htp.p('th, td {');
    htp.p('    border: 1px solid #000;');
    htp.p('    text-align: center;');
    htp.p('    padding: 8px;');
    htp.p('}');
    htp.p('th {');
    htp.p('    background-color: #ddd;');
    htp.p('}');
    htp.p('tr:nth-child(even) {');
    htp.p('    background-color: #f2f2f2;');
    htp.p('}');
  

    htp.p('</style>');
 htp.p('<table>');

htp.p('<tr>');
htp.p('<thead>');
htp.p('<td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">');


htp.p('<table>');
                htp.p('<tr>');
                    htp.p('<td>رقم الشقة</td>');
                    htp.p('<td colspan="3">' || V_apartment_id || '</td>');
                    htp.p('<td>تاريخ الدفع</td>');
                    htp.p('<td colspan="3">' || v_date || '</td>');
                    
                    
                    
                htp.p('</tr>');
htp.p('</table>');


htp.p('</td>');
htp.p('</thead>');
htp.p('</tr>');



htp.p('<tr>');
htp.p('<td>');


    --header seciton
    
    --htp.p('<tr>');
    --htp.p('<td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">');
    --htp.p('</td>');
    --htp.p('</tr>');


    htp.p('<tr>');
    htp.p('<td>');

     -- Generating HTML markup for the tables in a vertical layout
    --htp.p('<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">'); -- Flex container for vertical layout

    -- Table for QR Code

htp.p('<table>');
    htp.p('<tr>');
        htp.p('<td>'); -- Invoice Details section
            htp.p('<table>');
               
                htp.p('<tr>');
                    htp.p('<td>من تاريخ</td>');
                    htp.p('<td colspan="3">' || v_fdate || '</td>');
                    
                htp.p('</tr>');
                htp.p('<tr>');
                    htp.p('<td>إلي تاريخ</td>');
                    htp.p('<td colspan="3">' || v_tdate || '</td>');
                    
                    
                htp.p('</tr>');
                htp.p('<tr>');
                    htp.p('<td>اسم العميل</td>');
                    htp.p('<td colspan="3">' || V_CUST_NAME || '</td>');
               
                htp.p('</tr>');
                htp.p('<tr>');
                    htp.p('<td colspan="5"></td>');
                htp.p('</tr>');
            htp.p('</table>');
        htp.p('</td>');
       
    htp.p('</tr>');
htp.p('</table>');
    htp.p('<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">');
    htp.p('<tr>');
    htp.p('<th>م</th>');
    htp.p('<th> رقم العميل</th>');
    htp.p('<th> اسم الشقة </th>');
    htp.p('<th> المبلغ</th>');
    htp.p('<th> طريقة الدفع</th>');
    htp.p('<th> تاريخ الدفع</th>');
    
    htp.p('</tr>');
   FOR item_row IN invoice_details LOOP
    BEGIN
        SELECT cust_name INTO V_CUST_NAME FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUST_ID = item_row.CUST_ID;
        
htp.p('<tr>');
htp.p('<td>' || counter || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_CUSTOMER_ID || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_DESC || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_AMOUNT || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_pay_method || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_pay_date || '</td>');
htp.p('</tr>');
        counter := counter + 1;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        htp.p('<tr>');
htp.p('<td>' || counter || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_CUSTOMER_ID || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_AMOUNT || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_pay_method || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_pay_date || '</td>');
htp.p('</tr>');
            counter := counter + 1;
        WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
htp.p('<tr>');
htp.p('<td>' || counter || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_CUSTOMER_ID || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_AMOUNT || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_pay_method || '</td>');
htp.p('<td>' || V_pay_date || '</td>');
htp.p('</tr>');
            counter := counter + 1;
    END;
END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
htp.p('No data found');
END;
```

[image: the error i got]
I tried to change the single and double qoute but still dosenot work.

can you hlep me?

Comment: That is not a photo of your javascript error, it is a photo of the apex toolbar indicating there is a javascript error - it's impossible to see what the javascript error is. To see the javascript error, open your browsers' developers console. That will show where the error is thrown.

Comment: I opend the browsers' developers console and know the error is (div_print1) is not defined.

Comment: Well... what does the "print" button do ? It seems it's expecting a div that is not in the page - not much more I can tell you...

Comment: how can i print more than one record of data in thw last table in my photo.the building has more than one appartment ,and each appartment has a record of data like: customer name ,payment date ,amount and payment method.when there are more than one recored i get error (Exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows)